# using Tinyscrollbar.js plugin with ajax loaded content

Tags: tinyscrollbar

I have a Backbone View that renders some content:

I then I make a simple call initializeScrollbar() after the content loads:

```
function initializeScrollbar() {
    $('#technologypartners_text').tinyscrollbar();
}
```

Thats all I did! The call to tinyscrollbar() sets of these errors:

But the Chrome console gives:
[image: chrome console]

Firefox firebug console gives:
[image: firefox console]

Not sure if theyre related but i must be the plugin, only wrote 1 line of code as per the intructions! Anybody have any clue why its doing this.

Answer (score 1):

All Ajax content inside a scrollable element should be updated in order to work properly.
Try this:

```
function initializeScrollbar() {
    $('#technologypartners_text').tinyscrollbar_update();
}
```

But your case seems to be a conflict error with the 'offsetHeight' between your application and the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Do you have al the necessary elements defined? You need to have the following elements defined in your html.

.viewport .overview. .scrollbar .track .thumb

Check baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar for a example.